Stepper Motor Accuracy

Here's an excerpt from a 17HF24-1805S datasheet. As I understand it, given the step angle and its accuracy, each step can range from 0.684 to 0.756 degrees. However, will the full rotation angle range from 359.964 to 360.036 or from 342 to 378 degrees? Can we improve accuracy with half-stepping / microstepping or will they make it worse?

revised

Since it is non-accumulative, 500 steps in 360 degrees are guaranteed precise, but each step has up to 5% error.  Microstepping improves resolution but not accuracy and reduces torque.
A toothed pulley/gear reduction might also improve resolution but degrade accuracy.  A technique used by old ST506 stepper HDD's was to use a precision steel band with a pulley to achieve stability with half-stepping.
Microstepping is certainly smoother but with 500 steps per rev a full step is 0.2% of the revolution and +/- 5% of each step is 0.01 % of a full revolution or 100 ppm/rev.  This depends on the machined slots.
If you need a better absolute error of less than +/-1 part in 10k/rev or 100ppm then you need a better analog servo or more $$.
There is also dynamic error from mechanical resonance.
The biggest improvement I saw in the 80's testing every product on the market back then (worth > $5k in today's$ for 20 MB LOL) was a thin disc damper on the motor with oil filled on a brass disk embedded in clear plastic made by Nippon Peripherals Ltd of Hitachi. This prevented the massive ringing and overshoot about the same diameter as the stepper motor and 4mm thick or so.
Optical encode feedback is used for better error correction with diffraction gratings used in at least one HDD or slotted encoders in servo systems. 10k/rev and up is possible or linear types.  If you can specify your absolute error tolerance, perhaps I can assist you.
Oriental Motor is a good source and stiction from cables, rails & loads may increase absolute error with hysteresis.

Thanks! Yeah, it's plenty accurate for me, but it's hard for me to gauge pricing, 56$ for an accuracy of a full rotation within 0.036 degrees feels suspicious, but the brand seems legitimate, so I'm really second guessing :)

Half step is OK if 50 ppm resolution and 100 ppm accuracy helps you.

Best to go with popular brands as a DVT Engineer for HDD's,  suppliers need to verified for good reasons. Even Nidec Fans I disqualified until they fixed their Hall Sensor accuracy to prevent deadspots and stalled fans.  I even stopped Seagate's product line with a particle count test error in their process when they were making 100k drives /day. They had designed a fix overnight and implemented next day.

Oriental Motor is a good source.

My application requires low rpms - from 20 to 500 rpm, so I'm thinking an encoder would be unnecessary?

I don't know your system specs and details

There's always 360 degrees in a full circle. There's also always exactly 'N' (in this case N=500) steps in a full circle. See the below image from Oriental Motor:

If you take as a reference point a certain step, the center of each step will be accurate to within +/-5% of 0.72° from the ideal center point (or maybe you have to average the points to get the center, but you get the meaning). That's due to the mechanical tolerances of the pole locations, shaft centering and so on.
Microstepping is (ideally) a linear interpolation between the closest two steps so it will vary similarly and will not increase the accuracy, only the resolution. If those two points happen to be off by the same amount in the same direction, then the center and all other points between them will similarly be off.
Also, note that as you approach the maximum torque the error will increase to a good fraction of a step (a real step, not a microstep). The 5% datasheet number is the best-case unloaded situation. Real situations will almost always be worse because there is some torque or added friction.

The accuracy is non-cumulative, therefore the error does not build upon itself each step taken. Basically, the motor angle will always be within 5% of a step size from its theoretical position, and the full rotation angle ranges from 359.964 to 360.036 (I'm trusting your math on these numbers I haven't checked this myself). This makes sense when you rectify it with the mechanical design of a stepper motor. And yes, in general the accuracy of stepper motors increases with smaller step size introduced via micro-stepping.
